# How do the quid-pro-quo Ambassador deals work behind the scenes?

Tags: united-states, embassy, political-appointments

It seems like deals where people pay money to become an Ambassador are quite routine in US politics: [Why is it ethical for Ambassador Sondland to have been given an ambassadorship for campaign contributions?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/47948/why-is-it-ethical-for-ambassador-sondland-to-have-been-given-an-ambassadorship-f/47959#47959)

Is it known how these deals generally work behind the scenes? I.e. can any random millionaire just call up their local DNC/RNC office, come in for some haggling, then walk out with a promise to get a position if Biden/Trump is elected next year? Or does one need to first know the right people and it's not as easy to just pay money and get the job?

Comment: The same way all quid-pro-quo deals work in politics? Someone offers up enough to those who are willing to listen and if they don't have any major issues with the person they get appointed? Though that won't happen with a local or national DNC/RNC office as they would work with Biden/Trump themselves.

Comment: @JoeW right but how does that work exactly? Say I've got $1m lying around, how do I become an Ambassador to Thailand?

Comment: How it works is likely going to be different based on who is donating money and who is receiving it. A right wing donor is unlikely to get any position from a left wing president (and same with leanings switched) regardless of how much they donate. But a centrist might depending on the people in question. There is no one way this works out.